# How to return ActionErrors, FieldErrors as JSON and display errors on the form using AJAX

Tags: java, json, validation, struts2, liferay

I am wondering if anybody can throw any ideas on the following.

Got an Action class with `validate()` method returning input JSP with `actionErrors`, `fieldErrors` when validations fail.

I would like to get only the validation errors (JSON data?) and display the errors on the existing page and highlight the fields, rather than refreshing whole JSP with new response JSP.

JQuery is used on client side, Struts2 as MVC framework, Liferay as Portal server.

**The following is the code that I tried:**

```java
public void validate() { 
    setActionErrors(validateData(this));
}
```

**struts.xml:**

```xml
<result-types>
        <result-type name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONResult"/>
</result-types>
    
<interceptors>
    <interceptor name="json" class="org.apache.struts2.json.JSONInterceptor"/>
</interceptors>             


<action name="saveDataAsync" class="MyActionClass" method="addDataAsync">
    <result name="success">/jsp/addDataAsync.jsp</result>
    <result name="input" type="json">
    </result>
</action>
```

**JSP:**

```jsp
<portlet:actionURL name="saveData" var="saveDataActionURL">
   <portlet:param name="struts.portlet.action" value="/saveDataAsync"/>
</portlet:actionURL>
```

**Js:**

```js
jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: "<%=saveDataActionURL%>", 
            data: jQuery("#form").serialize(),
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(data) {
            
                alert("data" + data);
            }
});
```

After execution of validate method. the flow is executing default method of action class, even when there are errors added to errorlist and set through `setActionErrors()` method. I could see resultcode : as  `"input"` and result: as `"jsonresult"` when the interceptors and invoke methods get called.

I really appreciate any help on this problem.

Comment: You can expose the action errors like any other field; check out the docs.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure `INPUT` result to your action of type `json` and use `includeProperties` parameter to specify generated JSON.

```
<result name="input" type="json">
  <param name="ignoreHierarchy">false</param>
  <param name="includeProperties">^actionErrors\[\d+\],^fieldErrors\['\w+'\]\[\d+\]</param>
</result>
```

The action class should extend `ActionSupport`, so these properties will be available.

Comment: the following worked :  <result name="input" type="json">        <param name="root">fieldErrors</param><param name="wrapPrefix"><![CDATA[{ "errors" : ]]></param><param name="wrapSuffix"><![CDATA[}]]></param></result>  But I would like to have both action, field errors and I tried ,  <result name="input" type="json">
        <param name="includeProperties">^actionErrors\[\d+\]\.*,^fieldErrors\['\w+'\]\.*</param>
        <param name="wrapPrefix"><![CDATA[{ "errors" : ]]></param>
        <param name="wrapSuffix"><![CDATA[}]]></param>
      </result> Not Worked, retrurned LOG: obj {"errors":{}}